# Unwanted Padding Can't find issue

Tags: html, css, padding

I just started working on a small project for a friend and I am have a little issue that I cannot figure out.

Here is the test url: http://swampfighter.bmdigitalgroup.com/

If you look at the main content area where the rotating slider is, there is about 15 pixels padding at the bottom.

I cannot for the life of me figure out where this issue is. Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gumby.css` Line no. 110 you have this css rule

```
li {
    padding-bottom: 0.273em;
}
```

In flexslider, slide images are arranging in `li`.

So the padding is coming from this `li` css rule.

Comment: Ah! Awesome! What a great catch.. Thanks so much!